# How to make a join on a table in an sql query that contains several others?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am a beginner in SQL, I have an sql query that returns information I need on a table, the table `ARTICLE_MODE`:

| GA_CODEARTICLE | C1 | C2 | C3 | GA_LIBELLE | C5 | C6 | GA_LIBREART3 | GA_LIBREART5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BUTSS5-RC | SURF HARD WARE | - | Wetsuits | DAY COVER | 2021 | UNISEXE | SURF | SOF |

I need to retrieve information on a column of a second table.
The column `MZS_DPAETAST` of the table `MTMPTVGEN`.

In these two tables, two columns contain some identical information:

The `GA_CODEARTICLE` column from the `ARTICLE_MODE` table.

The column `MZS_ARTICLE` of the table `MTMPTVGEN`.

| GA_CODEARTICLE | MZS_ARTICLE |
| --- | --- |
| BUTSS5-RC | BUTSS5-RC |
| BUTS85-RC | BUTS85-RC |
| BUTS75-RC | VMA045-VC |

I tried to do this query to retrieve the values of the column `MZS_DPAETAST` which have as common values `GA_CODEARTICLE` and `MZS_ARTICLE`, it returns me many results:

```
select MZS_DPAETAST from MTMPTVGEN LEFT OUTER JOIN ARTICLE_MODE on MZS_ARTICLE=GA_CODEARTICLE
```

But how can I insert it in my initial query? Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT GA_CODEARTICLE, CC1.CC_LIBELLE AS C1, 
YX2.YX_LIBELLE AS C2, 
YX3.YX_LIBELLE AS C3, 
GA_LIBELLE, 
CC4.CC_LIBELLE AS C5, 
CC5.CC_LIBELLE AS C6,
CC6.CC_LIBELLE AS C15,
GA_LIBREART3,
GA_LIBREART5
FROM ARTICLE_MODE  
LEFT OUTER JOIN PGI_LOOKUP(GCFAMILLENIV1) CC1 ON GA_FAMILLENIV1=CC1.CC_CODE 
AND CC1.CC_TYPE="FN1"   
LEFT OUTER JOIN PGI_LOOKUP(GCLIBREART1) YX2 ON GA_LIBREART1=YX2.YX_CODE 
AND YX2.YX_TYPE="LA1"   
LEFT OUTER JOIN PGI_LOOKUP(GCLIBREART2) YX3 ON GA_LIBREART2=YX3.YX_CODE 
AND YX3.YX_TYPE="LA2"   
LEFT OUTER JOIN PGI_LOOKUP(GCCOLLECTION) CC4 ON GA_COLLECTION=CC4.CC_CODE 
AND CC4.CC_TYPE="GCO"  
LEFT OUTER JOIN PGI_LOOKUP(GCFAMILLENIV2) CC5 ON GA_FAMILLENIV2=CC5.CC_CODE 
AND CC5.CC_TYPE="FN2"
LEFT OUTER JOIN PGI_LOOKUP(GCFAMILLENIV5) CC6 ON GA2_FAMILLENIV5=CC6.CC_CODE 
AND CC6.CC_TYPE="FN5"  
WHERE (GA_EMBALLAGE<>"X" 
AND (GA_TYPEARTICLE NOT IN ("PRE","FI","FRA","UL","PAC"))
AND ((GA_STATUTART="GEN")))  
ORDER BY GA_DATEMODIF DESC
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using, by the way? You should always tag SQL requests with the DBMS in question, because SQL dialects can differ a lot, so the correct answer may depend heavily on the DBMS sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to uderstand what you are having problems with. You are showing you know how to join `article_mode` and `mtmptvgen`. You have a query containing `article_mode`. So what keeps you from joining `mtmptvgen` there?

Your query has many outer joins. I cannot know whether these are really necessary. I don't now for `mtmptvgen` either. I am showing an outer join, but you can make this an inner join if that suffices of course.

```
SELECT 
  am.ga_codearticle, 
  cc1.cc_libelle as c1, 
  yx2.yx_libelle as c2, 
  yx3.yx_libelle as c3, 
  am.ga_libelle, 
  cc4.cc_libelle as c5, 
  cc5.cc_libelle as c6,
  cc6.cc_libelle as c15,
  am.ga_libreart3,
  am.ga_libreart5,
  m.mzs_dpaetast
FROM article_mode am
LEFT OUTER JOIN pgi_lookup(gcfamilleniv1) cc1 ON am.ga_familleniv1  = cc1.cc_code AND cc1.cc_type = 'FN1'   
LEFT OUTER JOIN pgi_lookup(gclibreart1)   yx2 ON am.ga_libreart1    = yx2.yx_code AND yx2.yx_type = 'LA1'   
LEFT OUTER JOIN pgi_lookup(gclibreart2)   yx3 ON am.ga_libreart2    = yx3.yx_code AND yx3.yx_type = 'LA2'   
LEFT OUTER JOIN pgi_lookup(gccollection)  cc4 ON am.ga_collection   = cc4.cc_code AND cc4.cc_type = 'GCO'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN pgi_lookup(gcfamilleniv2) cc5 ON am.ga_familleniv2  = cc5.cc_code AND cc5.cc_type = 'FN2'
LEFT OUTER JOIN pgi_lookup(gcfamilleniv5) cc6 ON am.ga2_familleniv5 = cc6.cc_code AND cc6.cc_type = 'FN5'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN mtmptvgen m ON m.mzs_article = am.ga_codearticle
WHERE am.ga_emballage <> 'X'
AND am.ga_typearticle NOT IN ('PRE', 'FI', 'FRA', 'UL', 'PAC')
AND am.ga_statutart = 'GEN'
ORDER BY am.ga_datemodif DESC;
```

(I've added the missing column qualifiers and replaced the inappropriate double quotes with single quotes. These *are* supposed to be string literals, not column names, right? I also think that it makes queries hard to read when everything is in upper case and there are no spaces between operators, column names, and literals.)

### UPDATE

You say that there is just one `mzs_dpaetast` value per `article_mode`, but the data model is inappropriate and stores it redundantly in every related `mtmptvgen` row. In order to deal with this, you'll want to select one `mtmptvgen` row per `article_mode` row only. One way to do so is to join a query instead of the table:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT mzs_article, MAX(mzs_dpaetast) AS mzs_dpaetast
  FROM mtmptvgen
  GROUP BY mzs_article
) m ON m.mzs_article = am.ga_codearticle
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and clarification of the request, I understand better now. I didn't know if my join in my query was good to have the values that are in both tables at once and how to insert it in the middle of the others.

Comment: Ah, okay. As all tables are joined to `article_mode` only you can put the joins in any order; i.e. the order of the joins doesn't matter. You can join `mtmptvgen` as the first one or the second one, ... or as the last one. It makes no difference.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. And this query syntax can be applied to any type of database (MySQL, SQL Server...)?

Comment: Yes, this is standard SQL and should work in every RDBMS. (Except for MS Access, where additional parentheses are needed.)

Comment: Sorry to bother you but since you modified my query I have some duplicate values for the column 'ga_codearticle' and in my table there can't be any duplicates in this column. Is this due to the join to be changed? Or can we modify the query to not have duplicates in this column?

Comment: I don't know your data model. You join `article_mode` with many tables. Thus you get one result row for every combination of matches. If I have three tables x, y, and z and I join them, and a row in x has 2 matches in y and 2 matches in z, then I see the x row 4 times in my result (2 x 2 = 4). This is how joins work. If you didn't have duplicate `article_mode` rows in the results before, but have them now, then this means that an `article_mode` has more than one match in `mtmptvgen`. If you only want the `article_mode` row once in your result, which of it's `mtmptvgen` do you want to show?

Comment: Oh yes, I see the problem. The rows of the duplicate values are identical each time, it will be necessary to choose only one that emerges from the query but I do not know how to choose, there is no id column in the mtmptvgen table... The old joins are correct, I have no duplicate results. I would have to change the new join to have only unique results then?

Comment: That sounds like a bad data model. If the values are identical for an `article_mode`, why are they in the `mtmptvgen` table and not in the `article_mode` table? But well, I'll add a solution.

Comment: This model is from a software, I don't have the hand on it unfortunately and there are a lot of problems indeed, I try to adapt... thanks for your help